# How can I give a window msg higher priority then other window msgs (so that a window msg can not interrupt it) (c++)

Tags: c++, winapi, message-queue, i2c

I'm not really sure how to word this question, so hopefully this makes sense...

I have a GUI working that reads value from a board, and displays them in a window. This window also has a menu. My problem is, when I click on a menu item, it seems to jump out of my Update function before it has completed, which gives me a communication error from my board (since the command was not completed before switching over to the menu processing). The problem is intermittent, since I do not always click the menu when the Update function is running.

Some additional info:
The Update function is sent periodically using the following

PostMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, WM_USER+1, NULL);

```
case WM_USER+1:
{
    debugFunc = 2;
    Update();   
    InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
    debugFunc = 2;
}
```

The debugFunc integer was used for debugging...whenever the window sent WM_ENTERMENULOOP or WM_EXITMENULOOP, I would break to see what this debugFunc value was...whenever I had a communication error, the debugFunc == 4 (debugFunc is set in Update function to 4)...meaning that this WM_USER+1 msg did not complete before the menu was called.

So, is there a way to give either the message WM_USER+1 or the function Update a higher priority then the menu call? So that WM_USER+1 or Update must be completed before the menu items are shown?

EDIT:: Here's update, it just sends a bunch of messages using an I2C adapter to get reads..
I didnt write any of the iPortAIMaster functions, they came with the adapter

```
void Update()
{
    int receiveLength = 0;
    debugFunc = 4;
    //The following CStrings hold a string value that is to be updated to the window
    CString newVoltage, newCurrent, newPower, newStatus;
    CString StatusDisplay;

    //The following act like flags
    //If STATUS_WORD VOUT bit is set, checkVout = 1...meaning all pages must have their Vout Status checked
    //The rest follow in a similar fashion
    int checkTemp = 0, checkVout = 0, checkIout = 0, checkInput = 0;

    //Holds the pBuf data output from a MasterTxRx command is sent
    //Holds the new voltage or new current values
    //Must be translated to a CString to update the window
    BYTE *nV, *nC;

    //Holds a bit position
    int bit;
    float valueV, valueC;

        if (isOn)
        {
            pBufStatus[0] = 0x79;    //STATUS_WORD
            ////buf += "\r\n Sending the STATUS_WORD command to check for errors";
            //BYTE I2CAddr, BYTE *pBufStatus, unsigned int TxLen, unsigned int RxLen, BYTE doStop, UINT time
            newPort.iPortAIMasterTxRx(I2CAddr, pBufStatus, 1, 2, 1, 820);
            //Get the PAGE reading, value is placed in pBufStatus
            receiveLength = newPort.iPortAIGetMasterRxMsg(512, pBufStatus);
            //Store pBufStatus
            pBufWORD[0] = pBufStatus[0];
            pBufWORD[1] = pBufStatus[1];

    #pragma region "Reading and Updating the window"

    #pragma region "Reading new IN Volt Cur Pow"
    {
                valueV = 0;
                valueC = 0;

                //Read_VIN
                pBufStatus[0] = 0x88;       //Read_VIN Command
                pBufStatus[1] = 0;      //Clear out earlier command

                //Send Read_VIN command
                MasterTxRx(I2CAddr, pBufStatus, 1, 2, 1, 120);
                //Get the Voltage Reading, value is placed in pBufStatus
                newPort.iPortAIGetMasterRxMsg(512, pBufStatus);
                nV = pBufStatus;    //Save Copy

                //CONVERT THE VALUE TO USEABLE FORM
                valueV = ((int)valueV << 8) + pBufStatus[1];
                valueV = ((int)valueV << 8) + pBufStatus[0];
                //Multiply by 100 for formatting
                valueV = valueV / 100;

                newVoltage.Format("%.2f", valueV);

                //Read_IIN command
                pBufStatus[0] = 0x89;       //Read_IIN Command

                //Send Read_IIN command
                MasterTxRx(I2CAddr, pBufStatus, 1, 2, 1, 120);
                //Get the Voltage Reading, value is placed in pBufStatus
                newPort.iPortAIGetMasterRxMsg(512, pBufStatus);
                nC = pBufStatus;    //Save Copy

                //CONVERT THE VALUE TO USEABLE FORM
                valueC = ((int)valueC << 8) + pBufStatus[1];
                valueC = ((int)valueC << 8) + pBufStatus[0];
                //Multiply by 100 for formatting
                valueC = valueC / 100;

                newCurrent.Format("%.2f", valueC);

                newPower.Format("%.2f", (valueC*valueV));

                //SetWindowText(VoltIn, newVoltage);
                //SetWindowText(CurIn, newCurrent);
                //SetWindowText(PowIn, newPower);
                VoltInR = newVoltage;
                CurInR = newCurrent;
                PowInR = newPower;
    }
    #pragma endregion

    #pragma region "Reading new Temperatures"
    {
            valueV = 0;
            //READ_TEMPERATURE_1
            pBufStatus[0] = 0x8D;       //Read_VIN READ_TEMPERATURE_1
            pBufStatus[1] = 0;      //Clear out earlier command

            //Send READ_TEMPERATURE_1 command
            MasterTxRx(I2CAddr, pBufStatus, 1, 2, 1, 120);
            //Get the Voltage Reading, value is placed in pBufStatus
            newPort.iPortAIGetMasterRxMsg(512, pBufStatus);
            nV = pBufStatus;    //Save Copy

            //CONVERT THE VALUE TO USEABLE FORM
            valueV = ((int)valueV << 8) + pBufStatus[1];
            valueV = ((int)valueV << 8) + pBufStatus[0];
            //Multiply by 100 for formatting
            valueV = valueV / 100;

            newVoltage.Format("%.2f", valueV);
            //SetWindowText(TempU11, newVoltage);
            TempU11R = newVoltage;

            valueV = 0;
            //READ_TEMPERATURE_2
            pBufStatus[0] = 0x8E;       //Read_VIN READ_TEMPERATURE_2
            pBufStatus[1] = 0;      //Clear out earlier command

            //Send READ_TEMPERATURE_2 command
            MasterTxRx(I2CAddr, pBufStatus, 1, 2, 1, 120);
            //Get the Voltage Reading, value is placed in pBufStatus
            newPort.iPortAIGetMasterRxMsg(512, pBufStatus);
            nV = pBufStatus;    //Save Copy

            //CONVERT THE VALUE TO USEABLE FORM
            valueV = ((int)valueV << 8) + pBufStatus[1];
            valueV = ((int)valueV << 8) + pBufStatus[0];
            //Multiply by 100 for formatting
            valueV = valueV / 100;

            newVoltage.Format("%.2f", valueV);
            //SetWindowText(TempU12, newVoltage);
            TempU12R = newVoltage;

            valueV = 0;
            //READ_TEMPERATURE_3
            pBufStatus[0] = 0x8F;       //Read_VIN READ_TEMPERATURE_3
            pBufStatus[1] = 0;      //Clear out earlier command

            //Send READ_TEMPERATURE_3 command
            MasterTxRx(I2CAddr, pBufStatus, 1, 2, 1, 120);
            //Get the Voltage Reading, value is placed in pBufStatus
            newPort.iPortAIGetMasterRxMsg(512, pBufStatus);
            nV = pBufStatus;    //Save Copy

            //CONVERT THE VALUE TO USEABLE FORM
            valueV = ((int)valueV << 8) + pBufStatus[1];
            valueV = ((int)valueV << 8) + pBufStatus[0];
            //Multiply by 100 for formatting
            valueV = valueV / 100;

            newVoltage.Format("%.2f", valueV);
            //SetWindowText(TempU13, newVoltage);
            TempU13R = newVoltage;
    }
    #pragma endregion

            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                valueV = 0;
                valueC = 0; 

                //FOR LOOP Index thru pages
                //i = 0 +5V
                //i = 1 +3.3V
                //i = 2 +12V
                //i = 3 -12V
                //i = 4 +12V_AUX
                //i = 10    +28V_Input
                pBufStatus[0] = 0x00;           //Page Command
                pBufStatus[1] = (char)i;        //Page Number
                MasterTx(I2CAddr, pBufStatus, 2, 1, 60);

    #pragma region "Reading new OUT Volt Cur Pow"
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    {
                        //Read_VOUT
                        pBufStatus[0] = 0x8B;       //Read_Vout Command
                        pBufStatus[1] = 0;      //Clear out earlier command

                        //Send Read_VOUT command
                        MasterTxRx(I2CAddr, pBufStatus, 1, 2, 1, 120);
                        //Get the Voltage Reading, value is placed in pBufStatus
                        newPort.iPortAIGetMasterRxMsg(512, pBufStatus);
                        nV = pBufStatus;    //Save Copy

                        //CONVERT THE VALUE TO USEABLE FORM
                        valueV = ((int)valueV << 8) + pBufStatus[1];
                        valueV = ((int)valueV << 8) + pBufStatus[0];
                        //Multiply by 100 for formatting
                        valueV = valueV / 100;

                        newVoltage.Format("%.2f", valueV);

                        //Read_IOUT command
                        pBufStatus[0] = 0x8C;       //Read_Iout Command

                        //Send Read_IOUT command
                        MasterTxRx(I2CAddr, pBufStatus, 1, 2, 1, 120);
                        //Get the Voltage Reading, value is placed in pBufStatus
                        newPort.iPortAIGetMasterRxMsg(512, pBufStatus);
                        nC = pBufStatus;    //Save Copy

                        //CONVERT THE VALUE TO USEABLE FORM
                        valueC = ((int)valueC << 8) + pBufStatus[1];
                        valueC = ((int)valueC << 8) + pBufStatus[0];
                        //Multiply by 100 for formatting
                        valueC = valueC / 100;

                        newCurrent.Format("%.2f", valueC);

                        newPower.Format("%.2f", (valueC*valueV));
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                    {
                        //Read_VOUT
                        pBufStatus[0] = 0x8B;       //Read_Vout Command
                        pBufStatus[1] = 0;      //Clear out earlier command

                        //Send Read_VOUT command
                        MasterTxRx(I2CAddr, pBufStatus, 1, 2, 1, 120);
                        //Get the Voltage Reading, value is placed in pBufStatus
                        newPort.iPortAIGetMasterRxMsg(512, pBufStatus);
                        nV = pBufStatus;    //Save Copy

                        //CONVERT THE VALUE TO USEABLE FORM
                        valueV = ((int)valueV << 8) + pBufStatus[1];
                        valueV = ((int)valueV << 8) + pBufStatus[0];
                        //Multiply by 100 for formatting
                        valueV = valueV / 100;

                        newVoltage.Format("%.2f", valueV);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 10:
                    {
                        //Read_VOUT
                        pBufStatus[0] = 0x8B;       //Read_Vout Command
                        pBufStatus[1] = 0;      //Clear out earlier command

                        //Send Read_VOUT command
                        MasterTxRx(I2CAddr, pBufStatus, 1, 2, 1, 120);
                        //Get the Voltage Reading, value is placed in pBufStatus
                        newPort.iPortAIGetMasterRxMsg(512, pBufStatus);
                        nV = pBufStatus;    //Save Copy

                        //CONVERT THE VALUE TO USEABLE FORM
                        valueV = ((int)valueV << 8) + pBufStatus[1];
                        valueV = ((int)valueV << 8) + pBufStatus[0];
                        //Multiply by 100 for formatting
                        valueV = valueV / 100;

                        newVoltage.Format("%.2f", valueV);
                        break;
                    }
                }
    #pragma endregion

    #pragma region "Display reading"
                    switch (i)  //switch on the page number, display new values and checks faults if needed
                    {                       
                        case 0:         //+5V
                        {
        #pragma region "5V Display"
                            {
                                //SEND OUTPUT TO WINDOW USING SetWindowText();
                                //SetWindowText(Volt5at24, newVoltage);
                                Volt5at24R = newVoltage;
                                //SetWindowText(Cur5at24, newCurrent);
                                Cur5at24R = newCurrent;
                                //SetWindowText(Pow5at24, newPower);
                                Pow5at24R = newPower;
                                break;
                            }
        #pragma endregion
                        }
                        case 1:         //+3.3V
                        {
        #pragma region "3.3V Display"
                            {
                                //SEND OUTPUT TO WINDOW USING SetWindowText();
                                //SetWindowText(Volt3at15, newVoltage);
                                Volt3at15R = newVoltage;
                                //SetWindowText(Cur3at15, newCurrent);
                                Cur3at15R = newCurrent;
                                //SetWindowText(Pow3at15, newPower);
                                Pow3at15R = newPower;
                                break;
                            }
        #pragma endregion
                        }
                        case 2:         //+12V
                        {
        #pragma region "12V Display"
                            {
                                //SEND OUTPUT TO WINDOW USING SetWindowText();
                                //SetWindowText(Volt12at1, newVoltage);
                                Volt12at1R = newVoltage;
                                //SetWindowText(Cur12at1, newCurrent);
                                Cur12at1R = newCurrent;
                                //SetWindowText(Pow12at1, newPower);
                                Pow12at1R = newPower;
                                break;
                            }
        #pragma endregion
                        }
                        case 3:         //-12V
                        {
        #pragma region "-12V Display"
                            {
                                //SEND OUTPUT TO WINDOW USING SetWindowText();
                                //SetWindowText(Volt12at2, newVoltage);
                                Volt12at2R = newVoltage;
                            }
        #pragma endregion
                        }
                        case 4:         //+12V AUX
                        {
        #pragma region "12V AUX Display"
                            {
                                //SEND OUTPUT TO WINDOW USING SetWindowText();
                                //SetWindowText(Volt12at40, newVoltage);
                                Volt12at40R = newVoltage;
                            }
        #pragma endregion
                        }
                        case 10:            //+28V input
                        {
        #pragma region "3.3 HSKPR Display"
                            {
                                //SEND OUTPUT TO WINDOW USING SetWindowText();
                                //SetWindowText(VoltIn, newVoltage);
                                Volt3HR = newVoltage;
                                break;
                            }
        #pragma endregion
                        }
                    }
    #pragma endregion
                }
    #pragma endregion       
        }
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. There are no priorities in play here. The messages are pulled off and processed in order. The problem lies in the code we cannot see. You'll need to make an MCVE.

Comment: Does the same problem occur if you resize the window or other such modal window-handling?

Comment: What's inside `Update()`? Apparently, it yields - does something that allows window messages to get processed, resulting in window proc being reentered. The best way to make sure "Update must be completed before the menu items are shown" is to avoid yielding.

Comment: What does your Update() function do?

Comment: It sounds like you are either explicitly or implicitly processing message in your `Update()` call.

Comment: Anyway, you should get the board-reading code out of the GUI thread and allow the GUI thread to do GUI stuff.

Comment: I cant really make a MCVE though, since I am using a I2C adapter to talk to my board...The problem does not exist without the constant reads to the board through the adapter...

Comment: @HeatherSavage sounds like you need a real driver instead of whatever nasty polling stuff you have going on.

Comment: Messages are processed one after another. If you stack in one message, lets say WM_USER+1, then your application becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Do you have a `break;` statement in your code following the `case WM_USER+1:`? You haven't shown it in the snippet above.

Comment: Ok, I think that inside the adapters functions (which I didnt write) it may be processing messages...so I'll have to debug that tomorrow :(

@JonathanPotter I do have a break its after the {} I forgot to display it

Comment: When you break in `WM_ENTERMENULOOP` and discover you are still inside `Update`, look at the call stack. The function right above `Update` on the stack is the one that yields. I suspect that wrapper you use utilizes window messages somehow.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  Yes thank you! idk why I never thought about using the call stack, turns out that the adapters functions are processing messages...So I'll have to figure out a way to avoid it...darn :/ well thanks anyway for helping me find the problem

Comment: @LynnCrumbling no problem! Clearly Igor knows what he is talking about

Comment: As @MartinJames suggests, you may want to move your hardware interaction to a separate worker thread.